# bootstrap 3 slide left menu only on small screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, swipe

For a project i want to make a 2 column liquid site using bootstrap the left column as always will be a menu, and the right column is having the content

On large screens both columns must be visible, but on small screens i want to disappear the left menu and appear it using a swipe right gesture as in this tutorials:

http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html
http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

but the problem is that in those tutorials, the left menu is always hidden and no one uses bootstrap

does anyone knows a tutorial or can help me to achieve this?

Thanks!!